Tracking User Interactions in HubSpot iframe with Google Tag Manager
I’m working on tracking a page with Google Tag Manager that contains a HubSpot iframe, which is used for selecting a date and time for an appointment. I want to track the following user actions when interacting with the page:

Choosing a date: Click on the button with the classname
"date-picker-btn valid".
Choosing a time: Click on the div element with the classname
"time-picker-btn".
Starting to fill in their details: Input in a field with the
classname "form-control".
Submitting the form: Click on the button with the
data-test-id="forward-btn" attribute.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Seems like Hubspot is decent enough to send window messages to the parent on key events. Here's them guiding the tracking. In short, here is the callback:


window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormReady') {
    window.dataLayer.push({
      event: 'hubspotFormLoaded',
      hsFormGuid: event.data.id,
      currentUrl: window.location.href,
    });
  }

  if (event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmit') {
    window.dataLayer.push({
      event: 'hubspotFormSubmitting',
      hsFormGuid: event.data.id,
      currentUrl: window.location.href,
    });
  }

  if (event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
    window.dataLayer.push({
      event: 'hubspotFormSubmitted',
      hsFormGuid: event.data.id,
      currentUrl: window.location.href,
    });
  }
});



It's odd that hubspot doesn't have proper documentation for this kind of thing, but you could just see if their iframe passes the events on the actions you're interested in by console logging the event.data.type and the event.data.eventName in the listener above.
If they don't send events on the interactions you're interested in, then it's likely that you won't be able to track them. Not without having them issuing more events or allowing you to do that by deploying your code in their iframe. But that's unlikely to happen.
